# How to assign a variable name from a list then delete it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a function where it takes a list of names entered by the user. If there is an even number of players, it will randomly print out the names until there is no more names left. If there is an odd number, it will assign a variable name to the last name entered, then delete it from the list. Then it will do the same as the even number of players. I want to be able to use the last name later on in the program.

Here's what I have so far. It is giving me an error reading,

> "raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" %
>   (istart, istop, width)"

```
def randName(teamNames):
    if len(teamNames) % 2 ==0:
        randomname = random.randrange(0, len(teamNames))
        return teamNames.pop(randomname)
    else:
        lastName = teamNames[-1]
        teamNames.pop()
```

Comment: i don't get an error with this bit of code, supplying either an even-numbered or odd-numbered list of names. i get output of a single random name from the even list, and None from the odd list.

Comment: check if teamNames is not empty

Comment: @Stidgeon I want the output for the even number to be all the names and for the odd all the names with the exception of the last.

Comment: @Grace - I understand that the code doesn't do what you want, I'm just saying that I don't get the error that you get, so either something is missing from the posted code or I'm missing something (which is entirely possible).

Comment: @Stidgeon yeah, you're right. i tried the code on its own and it works the way you say. it must have been another piece of my code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import shuffle

def random_pairings(team_names):
    # randomize order
    team_names = list(team_names)
    shuffle(team_names)
    # remove 'odd man out'
    leftover = team_names.pop() if len(team_names) % 2 else None
    # get pairings
    trick = [iter(team_names)] * 2   # two pointers to *same* iterator
    pairs = list(zip(*trick))
    return pairs, leftover
```

which gives

```
>>> random_pairings("abcdefg")
([('g', 'c'), ('d', 'f'), ('b', 'e')], 'a')
```

so you can use it like

```
tennis_players = ["Dimitrov", "Herbert", "Sock", "Tomic", "Thiem"]

pairs, leftover = random_pairings(tennis_players)
for a,b in pairs:
    print("{} vs {}".format(a, b))
if leftover:
    print("{} sits this round out.".format(leftover))
```

giving

```
Tomic vs Herbert
Sock vs Dimitrov
Thiem sits this round out.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `randint`:

```
def randName(teamNames):
    if len(teamNames) % 2 ==0:
        randomname = random.randint(0, len(teamNames))
        return teamNames.pop(randomname)
    else:
        lastName = teamNames[-1]
        teamNames.pop()
```